# How do I see who's attending a feast?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

Feasts will often have events which give you choices which will either increase or decrease the opinion of every guest. That's all fine and dandy, but it be great if I could know exactly who's at the feast when I'm presented with these decisions, since there's some folks whose opinion is already so high that I don't really care about taking a small opinion penalty.

How can I see who the guests are at a feast?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is super unintuitive, but when you host a feast, a little tiny feast icon generates on the map when you're zoomed in close enough. I *think* it's always in your capital when you host it, but if you get invited to a vassal's feast, it'll be in their capital instead.[image]

When you click it, you get a nifty little pop-up with a list of all the persons attending!

[image]

Hunts and pilgrimages also generate a tiny location-specific icon, but I don't think those expand out to show who's with you. (This may be a bug)

Comment: What a handy menu to hide away where you can't really see it.

Comment: Clicking on your ruler's portrait in the character screen will zoom you to their current location, which lets you avoid having to figure out manually where a hosting vassal's capital is.